# virtualenv can't create env in project

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualenv

I'd like to create virtual environment in my distribution project on Catalina OS Mac.

I receive this feedback from terminal:

```
user@MBP-zen distribution % virtualenv env 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3241, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3225, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 585, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 598, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'zipp>=0.4' distribution was not found and is required by importlib-resource
user@MBP-zen ~ % which virtualenv
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

this is my python installed:

```
user@MBP-zen ~ % python
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 15:43:33) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I tested many answers given here as well as over internet but no success as for now. Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: then install zipp. `pip install zipp --upgrade`

Comment: thanks for comment. I have it done. Requirement already up-to-date. What interests me (and I am totally new to programming) is why does the traceback goes through Versions/2.7 despite the fact I have python 3.7.7.

Comment: oh, use pip3 then in above command.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Pipenv` which is also popular.

Run the following

```
pip3 install pipenv
```

Once you're inside the project directory, run the following-

```
pipenv install django
pipenv shell
```